# Three-Dimensional Heisenberg group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be the three dimensional Heisenberg group of quantum mechanics

Describe all the conjugacy classes in $H$ as subsets of $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Attempt: I was able to find the inner automorphism of the group defined by
$$
\alpha_{(x,y,z)}(x',y',z') = (x,y,z)(x',y',z')(x,y,z)^{-1} = (x',y',z'+x'y-xy')
$$
and from that found that the center of $H$ is of the form $(0,0,-z)$

But I'm not sure where to go from here. I know that there are there are
$$
|C| = \sum_{(j,k)\in \Bbb{Z}_n^2}\gcd(j,k,n)
$$
conjugacy classes in $H_n$, but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: What you does not seem to have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: I want to know, what is $G$?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake that I corrected- G is the three dimensional Heisenberg group, so G=H

Comment: From your description of $\alpha_{(x,y,z)}(x',y',z')$ you should be able to figure out when two elements $(x',y',z')$ and $(x'',y'',z'')$ of $H$ are in the same conjugacy class.

Comment: To add to what @AlexZorn said, to figure out what the conjugacy class of $(x', y', z')$ why don't you use your conjugacy formula, keep the $x', y', z'$ fixed and the $x, y, z$ arbitrary and see what collection of elements you get. You'll have to do some casework but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out what sets you can get.

Comment: Heisenberg group sometimes mean the one with real entries, sometimes with integer entries. You should clarify.